# Send two private messages and get a input from both in Discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I'm trying to make this Discord bot in python that when you give the command sends a private message to two people and try to get the message that is sent after

```
@client.command()
async def dm(ctx, member_1:discord.Member, member_2:discord.Member):
    await member_1.send(f'sup member 1 type something')
    await member_2.send(f'sup member 2 type something')

    def check(m):
            return m.author == ctx.author

    msg1 = await client.wait_for('message', check=check)

    def check_2(m):
            return m.member_2 == discord.Member

    msg2 = await client.wait_for('message', check=check_2)

    print(msg1.content)
    print(msg2.content)
```

my problem is that when the second member sends the message it gives me a error `'Message' object has no attribute 'member_2'`

if I delete the second member it works fine and gets my input and prints out what I typed but with the second member types something and it prints nothing, when the second member sends his message the error shows up

what should i put in the second check to work?

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is fix the second `return` statement.

Inside the `check` functions, `m` is the message that the function is supposed to check.
Of course this `m` will not have a `member_2` attribute by default.

But the real problem is: why are you checking

```py
m.member_2 == discord.Member
```

If you want to check if the author is a member (which it has to be) then you would have to type

```py
type(m.author) == discord.Member
```

What you want is to check if the author of that message is `member_2`. Then you have to type the same thing as you did in your first check function:

```py
return m.author == member_2
```

Here's the fixed code. By the way, I'm assuming that `msg_1` is the message that member 1 sends and not the `ctx.author`.

```py
    def check_1(m):
        return m.author == member_1  # checks if the person who sent it is member_1

    msg1 = await client.wait_for('message', check=check_1)

    def check_2(m):
        return m.author == member_2  # checks if the person who sent it is member_2

    msg2 = await client.wait_for('message', check=check_2)
```

Comment: really thankful for your answer man. have a good day